# trouble installing scikit-learn on mac osx 10.7.5

Tags: scikit-learn

with the below setup I am trying to install scikit-learn - the end goal is to use scikit-learn with python note book along side pandas for data manipulation.

tried pip same error, tried easy_install same error, tried scipy super package but it uses a 64 bit python distribution doesn't work along side pandas. So with the current setup how to I make the easy_install work for scikit. The failure occurs indicating that its unable to find C++ header files how do I fix this.

```
which python 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python

python
Enthought Python Distribution (EPD) free version -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.3-2 (32-bit)
(type 'upgrade' or see www.enthought.com/epd/upgrade to get the full EPD)
Python 2.7.3 |EPD_free 7.3-2 (32-bit)| (default, Apr 12 2012, 11:28:34) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin

Python version 2.7.3
scipy==0.10.1
numpy==1.6.1
pandas==0.10.1

easy_install -U scikit-learn
Searching for scikit-learn
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/
Reading http://scikit-learn.org
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/scikit-learn/files/
Reading http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net
Best match: scikit-learn 0.13.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scikit-learn/scikit-learn-0.13.1.tar.gz#md5=acba398e1d46274b8470f40d0926e6a4
Processing scikit-learn-0.13.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-FrggHE/scikit-learn-0.13.1/setup.cfg
Running scikit-learn-0.13.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-FrggHE/scikit-learn-0.13.1/egg-dist-tmp-mGaDaU
Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
In file included from /private/tmp/easy_install-FrggHE/scikit-learn-0.13.1/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp:6:
/private/tmp/easy_install-FrggHE/scikit-learn-0.13.1/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/svm.cpp:53:18: error: math.h: No such file or directory
/private/tmp/easy_install-FrggHE/scikit-learn-0.13.1/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/svm.cpp:54:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

..etc
```

Comment: Something's wrong with your compiler installation: the C++ compiler cannot find basic headers. Try reconfiguring or reinstalling Xcode (or whatever you use).

Comment: @larsmans. Thanks for the clue. I was indeed unable to find headers for the c++ libraries. Updated my gcc from using prebuilt binaries for osx mountain lion https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer. After install I was able to install scikit-learn 1) downloaded the scikit-learn package from github: a) https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn, b) run make and c) run sudo python2.7 setup.py install

Comment: That's great, happy sklearning!